# Opencv Imwrite is not saving images

Tags: python, opencv

I have this code which converts a csv file to images. I run it with no errors. but nothing happens and imwrite is not working.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import cv2

file = open('fer2013.csv')
dataReader = csv.reader(file)

X_train = []
X_test = []
y_train = []
y_test = []

for row in dataReader:
    if row[0] == 'emotion':
        continue

    y = int(row[0])
    X_str = row[1].split(' ')
    X = [int(x_str) for x_str in X_str]

    if row[2] == 'Training':
        X_train.append(X)
        y_train.append(y)
    else:
        X_test.append(X)
        y_test.append(y)

X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = np.array(y_train)
X_test = np.array(X_test)
y_test = np.array(y_test)

d = 0
while X_train.all():
    for image in X_train:
            image = image.reshape((48, 48))
            cv2.imwrite('E:/EmotionRec/test/dataset/%x.jpg'%d, image.astype(np.uint8))
            d+=1
```

What's wrong with my code or probably my loop including imwrite?

Comment: are you able to view the images using `cv2.imshow()`?

Comment: @JeruLuke No It doesn't work either.

Comment: after `image = image.reshape((48, 48))`, check the type of `image` using `type(image)`